# How can I create a method in a service that returns the result of onSnapshot and then using it in my Component or Ionic Page?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic3, google-cloud-firestore

I'am using "ionic-angular": "3.7.1" and Firebase Cloud Firestore. I want to get all the documents into the Post collection everytime   them are updated, deleted or added. I know that calling the onSnapshot Method I can get it so I defined this method in a service.

```
getPosts(token: string){
  const userId = this.authService.getActiveUser().uid;
  let posts = [];
  return firebase.firestore().collection("Post").onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
          posts.push(doc.data());
        });
        console.log("Posts: ", posts.join(", "));
        return posts;
      });
}
```

So in the console I can see all my posts inside the array Posts, but If a call this method using `this.post.getPosts(token)` in my component I get this output in the console:

```
ƒ () {
  asyncObserver.mute();
  firestoreClient.unlisten(internalListener);
}
```

So, How can I create a method in a service that returns the result of onSnapshot and then using it in my Component or Ionic Page?

Documentation

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query?hl=es-419

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen?hl=es-419

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

If you need to see how to implementment generic `service/provider` with `Firestore` please see [**this artcile**](http://masteringionic.com/blog/2017-10-22-using-firebase-cloud-firestore-with-ionic/).

**Old Feedback:**

You need to use **fat arrow** functions here and you have done a number of mistakes here. You can try below `code`.

```
  getPosts(token: string){
    const userId = this.authService.getActiveUser().uid;
    let posts = [];

     retrun firebase.firestore().collection("Post").get().then((querySnapshot)=> 
     {
       querySnapshot.forEach((doc)=> {
           posts.push(doc.data());
      });
        return posts;
     });
 }
```

[**Doc**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data)

Comment: Hi Sampath using fat arrow functions doesn't resolve the problem, arrow function are another way to write anonymous functions, so I get exactly the same result with this change.Hi Sampath that doesn't resolve the problem, arrow function are another way to write anonymous functions.

Comment: You must always use arrow functions with TS. Otherwise, you'll face a lot of `local/global scope` issues.

Comment: See the latest Update.

Comment: Now I get  {__zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value: Array(0)} if a print  console.log(this.post.getPosts(token)) when I call the method. And for what I understand the get method fetch the values once and not when a document changes.

Comment: You can refer this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Comment: How can you call an `Async` method like that? You can't

Comment: so how I should use it?

Comment: If a put this in my page it works perfect:     
               `firebase.firestore().collection("Post").onSnapshot((querySnapshot)=> {
          let allPost = [];
          querySnapshot.forEach((doc)=> {
            allPost.push(doc.data());
            });
          this.posts = allPost;
          }); `
But sadly I can't reuse my code as if it were in my service. Where did  you read that it can be used `Async` @Sampath ?

Comment: With this update I can write an `Async` call and reuse my code but `get()` doesn't listen de collection so it get the documents only once and not when they changes for this purpose it is used `ononSnapshot()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could implement it:

Return an Observable from your service:

```
getPosts(token: string) {
  const userId = this.authService.getActiveUser().uid;
  let posts = [];
  return new Observable(observer => {
    const unsubscribe = firebase.firestore().collection("Post").onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
      querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        posts.push(doc.data());
      });

        observer.next(posts);
      });

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  });
}
```

Then at your Component or Ionic Page:

```
const _this = this; // 'this' inside 'subscribe' refers to the observable object
this.postsObserver = this.branchService.getPosts(token);
this.postsObserver
  .subscribe({
    next(posts) {
      _this.posts = posts;
    },
    error(error) { console.log(error); }, // optional
  });
```

Every time you change any of your posts, that change would already reflect on the list without you having to call `getPosts` ever again.

**Note**:

Also, if your service is exclusive to `posts` (which I recommend), I recommend that you keep a single reference to `posts` collection when you init the service:

```
  this.postsRef = firebase.firestore().collection('Post');
```

`firebase.firestore().collection('Post')` doesn't count against your database quota, but it doesn't hurt to keep code look cleaner by using `this.postsRef` in all other subsequent queries to the said collection.

**Edit**:

Added the "teardown" function that gets called when the Observable is destroyed. In this case, when we destroy the Observable we stop firebase realtime listener from listening for more updates. Frees up more bandwidth for your client.

References:

- [Angular doc](https://angular.io/guide/observables)
- [Firebase doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen)
- [Learning Observables](https://medium.com/@benlesh/learning-observable-by-building-observable-d5da57405d87)